# C# Method Overloading Issue, string string[] conversion

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the below to work as follows. name(something) adds something to the list. and then name() retrieves the values. But I'm having some problems and was hoping one of you guys knows what's up.

```
public class PlayerSettings
{
    public List<string[]> Players = new List<string[]>();
    public void Name(string input)
    {
        string[] addname = new string[1];
        addname[0] = input;
        Players.Add(addname);
    }
    public string[] Name()
    {
        foreach (string[] Player in Players)
        {
            return Player[0];
        }
    }
}
```

cannot implicitly convert type string to string[] error on the line below.

```
return Player[0];
```

Comment: What is the problem..?

Comment: What exactly do you want to return in the method Name? Although to fix the error you need "return new string[] {Player[0]};", but this code doesn't make sense.

Comment: You need to tell us what problems you're having (other than a weird fetish for arrays - I don't see a reason why arrays are appearing in this code at all)

Comment: I am looking to return the value's that I added to the Player list.

Comment: I believe @user1511385 wants to add names to a list of player-settings (`string[]`) using `Name("foo")`, and to get a list of names by using `Name()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `Player[0]` is not of the type `string[]` it is just a string. Thus, the return type of the second `Name()` should be `string` and not `string[]`.

Also, I don't see the point in using a `string[]` inside a `List<>` since you are just inserting a single string and retrieving the same!

I think this modified code should be good for you:

```
public class PlayerSettings
{
    public List<string> Players = new List<string>();
    public void Name(string input)
    {
        Players.Add(input);
    }
    public string Name()
    {
       return Players.ElementAt(0);
    }
}
```

The first overload for `Name()` will add strings to the list while the second will return the first string that was added. You can also have another `Name()` to return based on the index like:

```
 public string Name(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < Players.Count())
            return Players.ElementAt(index);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this is pretty much what I was looking for, except I wanted all of the values joined together when I called for Name(), but I believe I can do that myself.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers as the best. The one which helped you understand most.

Answer (score 1):

you return element of array but not array, replace `public string[] Name()` to `public string Name()`

or if you need array with one item use `Array.Resize(*params*)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
public class PlayerSettings
{
    public List<String> Players = new List<String>();
    public void Name(String input)
    {
        Players.Add(input);
    }
    public IEnumerable<String> Names()
    {
        foreach (string Player in Players)
        {
            yield return Player;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want Name() to return a cumulated value, such as a comma separated string :

```
   public string Name()    {  return string.Join("," Players.Select(p=>p[0]));    }
```

If it should return a list with all the first values:

```
   public string[] Name()    {  return Players.Select(p=>p[0]).ToArray();    }
```

Comment: +1 for a creative name.  Also as it turns out you telepathically figured out that the OP wanted the values joined.  (He said so in a comment on naqvitalha's answer).

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you asked for:

```
public class PlayerSettings
{
    public List<string> Players = new List<string>();
    public void Name(string input)
    {
        Players.Add(input);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Name()
    {
        return Players;
    }
}
```

However, I am **certain** that that's not what you want.

Think about what you really want your code to do, specifically why you have a `List<string[]>` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the Player not Player[0] if you are willing to return the array of string.

Comment: It's obvious he wants to return an array of names, not an array of player settings.

Answer (score 0):

`Player[0]` is just one `string`.

But your method definition says you are returning an array of strings (`string[]`)

So just return `Players.ToArray()` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return` multiple times from a method. And I don't understand why the internal list is a list of *arrays* of string. I think you want something like:

```
public class PlayerSettings
{
    public List<string> Players = new List<string>();
    public void Name(string input)
    {
        Players.Add(input);
    }
    public string[] Name()
    {
        return Players.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your playersettings class like:

```
public class PlayerSettings
{
    private List<string[]> Players = new List<string[]>();
    public void Name(string input)
    {`enter code here`
        string[] addname = new string[1];
        addname[0] = input;
        Players.Add(addname);
    }
    public string[] Name()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (string[] Player in Players)
        {
            result.AddRange(Player);
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```